# Java: Populating .xsd-generated class from .xml file

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb2

I have a class that was generated from an .xsd file, and I have an .xml file that contains data that adheres to the schema in the .xsd.  Something like:

- XML schema file: `MyObject.xsd`
- Java class generated from schema: `MyObject.java`
- XML that matches the schema: `MyObject.xml`

Is there an easy way for me to deserialize `MyObject.xml` into an instance of `MyObject.java`? I'm hoping for something easier than hand-walking through the DOM elements and setting all the properties on the object.

Basically, I'm looking for the functionality in `java.beans.XMLDecoder`, but since my .xml file was not created from the `XMLEncoder`, I do not believe that I can use the decoder.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any information about how the Java class has been generated. Therefore it is impossible to answer it.

Comment: I generated them using the CXF library. Forgive me, I assumed that there would be one accepted generated class given an .xsd and therefore the details of the generation would be extraneous information.

Comment: Well, there are multiple libraries/APIs to map XML to Java (JAXB2, XMLBeans, Castor, etc.) and they work very differently, so it is obviously important to know which one you use. You say that you use CXF, but CXF itself is a Web services framework that supports multiple databinding libraries, so it's still not clear which one you actually use.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It is using JAXB2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a `JAXBContext` instance using the static `newInstance` method. Then create an `Unmarshaller` instance using the `createMarshaller` method and call the appropriate `unmarshal` method on that instance:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("MyObject.xml");
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObject.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
MyObject o = (MyObject)u.unmarshal(is);
```